# (C++) My CopyFile() function doesn't work, but my paths and parameter types seem to be ok

Tags: c++, windows, function, path

I'm trying to write a function which copies the current running program's `.exe` file to the Windows's `Startup` folder. I'm completely new to this, so don't be mad at me :D

I have this piece of code:

```
void startup()
{
    std::string str = GetClipboardText();
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(str.begin(), str.end());
    LPCWSTR sw = stemp.c_str();
    int a;
    if (CopyFile(buffer, sw, true))
        a = 1;
    else a = 0;
}
```

Here I get the paths and save them in `buffer` (like `D:\source\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe`, I checked if that's the right path, if I paste what `buffer` contains in File Explorer, it runs the right `.exe` file) and `sw` (like `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`). But it doesn't copy, and the simple `if` check shows `a=0`.

I thought it might not has the permission to copy files into the `Startup` folder, but it doesn't work with other "test" folders as well.

Comment: `std::wstring(str.begin(), str.end())` is the wrong way to convert a `std::string` to a `std::wstring`. Consider changing `GetClipboardText()` to return a `std::wstring` (using `CF_UNICODETEXT`) instead of a `std::string`

Comment: On a side note, you should not be copying the `.exe` file itself to the `Startup` folder, you should be using the `IShellLink` interface to create a shortcut to the original `.exe` file instead. See [Shell Links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/links) on MSDN. However, rather than using the Start Menu's `Startup` folder at all, consider putting the `.exe` file path in the user's [`Run` Registry key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CopyFile()` copies from one file to another file. So both `lpExistingFileName` and `lpNewFileName` parameters must be given *file* paths, but you are passing in a *folder* path for the `lpNewFileName` parameter.  That will not work.

Had you followed what the documentation says:

> If the function fails, the return value is zero. **To get extended error information, call GetLastError.**

`GetLastError()` would have told you that your inputs where unacceptable.

So, to fix this, you will have to extract and concatenate the source filename onto your destination folder path, eg:

```
std::wstring GetClipboardUnicodeText()
{
    // get clipboard text using CF_UNICODETEXT, return as std::wstring...
}

void startup()
{
    std::wstring str = GetClipboardUnicodeText();

    WCHAR src[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, src, MAX_PATH);

    WCHAR dest[MAX_PATH] = {};
    PathCombineW(dest, str.c_str(), PathFindFileNameW(src));

    int a = CopyFileW(src, dest, TRUE);
}
```

Otherwise, to copy a file into a folder without specifying a target filename, use `SHFileOperation()` instead, eg:

```
void startup()
{
    // note the extra null terminator!
    std::wstring dest = GetClipboardUnicodeText() + L'\0';

    // note +1 for the extra null terminator!
    WCHAR src[MAX_PATH+1] = {};
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, src, MAX_PATH);

    SHFILEOPSTRUCTW op = {};
    op.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    op.pFrom = src;
    op.pTo = dest.c_str();
    op.fFlags = FOF_FILESONLY;

    int a = SHFileOperationW(&op);
}
```

Comment: got it, changed the function to return unicode string and used SHFileOperation, it worked just fine. But still I'll try to use register keys, seems more convenient, thanks for advice :)